# Message from nvm every time I start a new shell?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvm, fish, windows-terminal

I have just setup fedora in WSL. I installed nvm and I get this message every time I run a new shell

> Reverting to default Node version
> Now using node v18.12.0 (npm v8.19.2)

I'm using the `fish shell` with `Oh My Fish`. I installed nvm per the instructions on the nvm github page. I also added the configuration needed for fish. I have only installed 18.12.0 after I installed nvm. Everything works fine its just more of an annoyance than anything else. Would like to figure out why its happening though. This probably doesn't matter but using `WSL2`

**Edit:**
Thanks @faho. In reviewing the config files to submit to the post I found out where its happening:

```
function load_nvm --on-variable="PWD"
  set -l default_node_version (nvm version default)
  set -l node_version (nvm version)
  set -l nvmrc_path (nvm_find_nvmrc)
  if test -n "$nvmrc_path"
    set -l nvmrc_node_version (nvm version (cat $nvmrc_path))
    if test "$nvmrc_node_version" = "N/A"
      nvm install (cat $nvmrc_path)
    else if test "$nvmrc_node_version" != "$node_version"
      nvm use $nvmrc_node_version
    end
  else if test "$node_version" != "$default_node_version"
    echo "$default_node_version"
    echo "$node_version"
    echo "Reverting to default Node version"
    nvm use default
  end
end
```

As you can see its hitting the `else if` above. I outputed the variables as you can see above & :

```
none
v18.12.0
Reverting to default Node version
Now using node v18.12.0 (npm v8.19.2)
```

As you can see from the output above $node_version is `null`. Not sure why. Doing `nvm version` in a shell yields:
[image]

Comment: Please add the configuration you have added. This message is printed by something you run, and most likely you just need to tell it to be quiet, by adding a `--quiet` flag or silencing it with `>/dev/null`.

Comment: Thanks @faho. In reviewing the scripts i was able to find out `where` they issue is not sure of the `why` though.